# Does anyone have a better way to monitor IIS application pools?

Tags: iis, iis-6, application-pool

I would like to create a `"System Health"` web page which will monitor the application pools running on a web server.

The web server has several application pools and is an Intranet (so no big security problems). 
Periodically it seems that some of these pools will hang/crash etc. and the recycle wont pick it up. (Separate problem)

My idea is to have a single web page which will fire a request to a known url in each application pool, and if a good response is received, then mark it as `OK` otherwise it will mark it as `FAILED`. This would be displayed as a table with traffic lights perhaps.

I'd probably use c# for this.

Does this sound reasonable?
Does anyone have a better way of monitoring application pools?

p.s I realise that if the application pool running this page were to crash then nothing would show up at all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good article for using PerfMon with C#:

[How To: Monitor the ASP.NET Thread Pool Using Custom Counters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms979194.aspx)